# Setting spring.cloud.config.failFast in an Environment Variable

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I have written a spring boot service that is a spring cloud config client. I need to set the following configuration in an environment variable...

```
spring.cloud.config.failFast
```

the normal convention for doing this is to capitalize everything and replace the periods with underscores like

```
SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_FAILFAST
```

This hasn't worked for me. I think it may be because "failFast" is camel case and almost all other configs are lower case. Has anyone been able to set this configuration in an environment variable? If so what was the syntax?

Comment: Have you tried fail_fast?

Comment: well, it seems to work now. I swear I tried that before. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

By convention, you need replace the DOT and DASH for UNDERLINE.

propertie to replace: spring.cloud.config.fail-fast

replaced propertie:**SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_FAIL_FAST**